# How to visualize Azure Cost Management view in Grafana

Tags: azure, grafana, cost-management, azure-monitor

I have integrated Azure and Grafana using Azure Monitor plugin, how can I get Cost related data from Azure to Grafana ? I checked some metrics couldn't find anything related to costs.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Your question needs some work so the community can better help you. Take a look at [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and give it another try.

Comment: Add at least a screenshot